# A dict and a list of dicts: conversion and when to use which

Tags: python, list, dictionary

1. How can we convert a dict with tuples (key, value), into a list of
   dicts, each dict with keys "key" and "value"?

   For example:

   ```
   dic={'Tim':3, 'Kate':2}
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   lst = [{'Name':'Tim', 'Age':3}, {'Name':'Kate', 'Age':2}]
   ```
2. What are some advantages and disadvantages of using each
   representation? (e.g. consider the operations which we can think of
   and apply to them naturally). Thanks.

Comment: in a dict key look up is O(1) ... in a list you are looking at O(N) to find a given entry

Comment: Didn't you ask this question like a week ago?

Comment: Are they the same? @Shash?

Comment: @Tim Hmm...I guess not. I was just having deja vu. But anyways, I believe this link will help you a lot in determining which data structure to use and when: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity :)

Comment: @joran: Thanks. Nice to know it. By the way, ,my purpose is to [print the original dictionary into a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29265002/print-a-dictionary-into-a-table).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension :

```
>>> dic={'Tim':3, 'Kate':2}
>>> [{'Name':i, 'Age':j} for i,j in dic.items()]
[{'Age': 3, 'Name': 'Tim'}, {'Age': 2, 'Name': 'Kate'}]
```

and for opposite :

```
>>> l=[{'Name':i, 'Age':j} for i,j in dic.items()]
>>> dict((i.values()[::-1] for i in l))
{'Tim': 3, 'Kate': 2}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to do the opposite: from a list of dictionaries with same keys, to a dictionary?

Comment: that reversal function is dangerous as dicts do not have order you are not guaranteed the right order ...

Answer (score 4):

Dictionary to list of dictionary

```
>>> dic={'Tim':3, 'Kate':2}
>>> [{"Name":i, "Age":j} for i,j in dic.items()]
[{'Age': 3, 'Name': 'Tim'}, {'Age': 2, 'Name': 'Kate'}]
>>>
```

---

Best to use Dictionary Data Structure because Time Complexity to Find Key is `O(1)` Constant  Time  i.e. it is not depend on the size of dictionary

**Demo to find age of Kate.**

Need to Iterate every element from the List. Time Complexity is from O(1) to O(N)

```
>>> info
[{'Age': 3, 'Name': 'Tim'}, {'Age': 2, 'Name': 'Kate'}]
>>> age = -1
>>> find_name = "Kate"
>>> for i in info:
...    if i["Name"]==find_name:
...      age = i["Age"]
...      break
... 
>>> age
2
>>>
```

By dictionary: Time Complexity is O(1)

```
>>> dic = {'Tim':3, 'Kate':2}
>>> find_name = "Kate"
>>> if find_name in dic:
...    age = dic[find_name]
... else:
...    age = -1
...    print "No data for %s name"%find_name
... 
>>> age
2
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

```
>>> dic={'Tim':3, 'Kate':2}
>>> map(lambda x: x,dic)
['Tim', 'Kate']
>>> map(lambda x:{'Age':dic[x],'Name':x},dic)
[{'Age': 3, 'Name': 'Tim'}, {'Age': 2, 'Name': 'Kate'}]
>>>
```

Note  - `map` is slower compared to a list comprehension, but I have just added it as an alternative