# Print a dictionary into a table

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
dic={'Tim':3, 'Kate':2}
```

I would like to output it as:

```
Name Age
Tim 3
Kate 2
```

Is it a good way to first [convert them into a list of dictionaries,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29264845/156458)

```
lst = [{'Name':'Tim', 'Age':3}, {'Name':'Kate', 'Age':2}]
```

and then write them into a table, by the method in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10373268/156458?

Or is there a way better in some sense?

Comment: Where are the attribute names stored?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - Printing a dictionary as a horizontal table with headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330139/python-printing-a-dictionary-as-a-horizontal-table-with-headers)

Comment: @Ved: in the table, as the first row

Comment: no need to convert it to a list, print the header row, then iterate through key-value pairs and print the key, followed by the value

Comment: Tim, it is better if you add the version you are using. As in [tag:python-2.7] or [tag:python-3.x]

Comment: You can test multiple methods by using the `timeit` module. Here, I have run some tests for you: http://repl.it/f2W/1 To run more intensive tests, I recommend using your terminal because repl.it is slow. Using `dic.items()` seems to be the most consistently fast way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rather than convert to a list of dictionaries, directly use the `.items` of the dict to get the values to display on each line:

```
print('Name Age')
for name, age in dic.items():
    print(f'{name} {age}')
```

In versions before 3.6 (lacking f-string support), we can do:

```
print('Name Age')
for name, age in dic.items():
    print('{} {}'.format(name, age))
```

Answer (score 11):

You could use pandas.

```
In [15]: import pandas as pd

In [16]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Tim':3, 'Kate':2}.items(), columns=["name", "age"]) 

In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
   name  age
0   Tim    3
1  Kate    2
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it directly as in

```
>>> print("Name\tAge")
Name  Age
>>> for i in dic:
...     print("{}\t{}".format(i,dic[i]))
... 
Tim 3
Kate    2
>>>
```

It displays even better if executed as a script

```
Name    Age
Tim     3
Kate    2
```

And for the other representation

```
lst = [{'Name':'Tim', 'Age':3}, {'Name':'Kate', 'Age':2}]
print("Name\tAge")
for i in lst:
    print("{}\t{}".format(i['Name'],i['Age']))
```

And for your final question - *Is it a good way to first convert them into a list of dictionaries* Answer is **No**, A dictionary is hashed and provides faster access than lists

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way,

```
format = "{:<10}{:<10}"    
    print format.format("Name","Age")
    for name,age in dic.iteritems():
       print format.format(name,age)
```

I have written a simple library to pretty print dictionary as a table 
https://github.com/varadchoudhari/Neat-Dictionary
which uses a similar implementation

Answer (score 1):

Iterate dictionary and print every item.

Demo:

```
>>> dic = {'Tim':3, 'Kate':2}
>>> print "Name\tAge"
Name    Age
>>> for i in dic.items():
...    print "%s\t%s"%(i[0], i[1])
... 
Tim 3
Kate    2
>>>
```

**By CSV module**

```
>>> import csv
>>> dic = {'Tim':3, 'Kate':2}
>>> with open("output.csv", 'wb') as fp:
...     root = csv.writer(fp, delimiter='\t')
...     root.writerow(["Name", "Age"])
...     for i,j in dic.items():
...         root.writerow([i, j])
... 
>>>
```

Output: output.csv file content

```
Name    Age
Tim     3
Kate    2
```

We can use `root.writerows(dic.items())` also

Comment: how to write, not to a file, but to the console or say the stdout? in other words, how to print in this manner?

Answer (score 1):

If you go for higher numbers, then having number in the first column is usually a safer bet as you never know how long a name can be.

Given python3:

```
dic={'Foo':1234, 'Bar':5, 'Baz':123467}
```

This:

```
print("Count".rjust(9), "Name")
rint("\n".join(f'{v:9,} {k}' for k,v in dic.items()))
```

Prints

```
    Count Name
    1,234 Foo
        5 Bar
  123,467 Baz
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for each in zip(*([i] + (j) for i, j in c.items())):
    print(*each)
```

Comment: for each in zip(*([i]+(j) for i,j in dict.items())):
        print(*each)

Comment: Hey @yash-goyal, consider making your snippet a markdown code block. Doing so would improve legibility for other viewers and your answer looks cooler ;) Hope you enjoy your journey on the platform!